# Permission Error when using pg_read_binary_file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to load an excel file into postgres 10 database using `pg_read_binary_file` and I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: could not open file "<file-name>" for reading: Permission Denied
```

The file is in the `PGDATA` folder and I have tried changing the permissions and ownership to just about everything i can think of. Currently the file permissions are rw-rw-rw- and the owner is postgres:postgres. The command I am using is as follows:

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <column> = pg_read_binary_file('<filename>');  
WHERE <primary_key>=<key>;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the *exact* file name you are using.

Comment: First of all: don't put user-files there.

Comment: @wildplasser From what I've read that is the only location pg_read_binary_file will read from. I usually don't have anything in there.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't know what difference the exact filename I'm using is. If it makes any difference it is an .xlsx file and there are no spaces or other unusual characters in the filename (there are underscores though). I've already tested to make sure the filename is correct and I get a different error if I mistype the filename.

Comment: I was asking for the exact file name because I wanted to know whether you are using absolute or relative paths. Since you get a different error message if you try with a non-existent file, I'd guess that you are lacking permissions on one of the directories on the path. We are not going to steal your file if you tell us the correct name (how should we?), it just makes it easier to help.