# Permission Denied in PostgreSQL when using pg_read_binary_file

Tags: database, postgresql, image

I'm trying to add a photo to my database using PostgreSQL. I'm not trying to store the image as a file reference (as this is a personal project and I'm not concerned about scalability), and I'm instead using `pg_read_binary_file` as a recommended option to store the photo; however, I've inserted the absolute file path for the function, and it's returned the following error:

*ERROR: could not open file "C:/Users/User1/Documents/VS Code/Public/Ecom_Mahjong/client/src/assets/products/Shirt3.png" for reading: Permission denied*

It seems a similar question has been asked before, but never got resolved:

[Permission Error when using pg_read_binary_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838870/permission-error-when-using-pg-read-binary-file)

What should I check for to correct this solution and insert the photos into my database?

```
INSERT INTO products(product, description, price, image) VALUES ('Mahjong Hoodie', '
Stay cozy in style with our Mahjong-themed hoodie, featuring intricate tile designs and a comfortable fit for all-day gaming sessions.', 24.99, pg_read_binary_file('C:\Users\User1\Documents\VS Code\Public\Ecom_Mahjong\client\src\assets\products\Shirt3.png') );
```

Comment: that is a personal folder the postgres has no rights to read it, use a folder that has rigt for all users

Comment: how might I go about checking for that? Can I grant PostgreSQL access to certain folders, or would it be best practice to just drop my image files into 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16rc1\data', which seems like the pre-assigned data directory for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides being restricted to **superusers**, Postgres allows direct file access only in **certain directories** to begin with. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE):

> Only files within the database cluster directory and the `log_directory`
> can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster
> directory, and a path matching the `log_directory` configuration setting
> for log files.

You can overcome the path restriction with a symlink from your db directory to any other directory. Be wary of possible security implications, though!

Similar questions got asked *and* resolved before:

- [Read binary file with PostgreSQL without pg_read_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310619/read-binary-file-with-postgresql-without-pg-read-file/65752187#65752187)
- [Read data from a text file inside a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097854/read-data-from-a-text-file-inside-a-trigger/13098221#13098221)